# How to target through input id in selenium webdriver?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

- Currently working on selenium webdriver and i want to select a value from the drop down it is a type of date picker.
- There the calender in the form of **Year** as drop down and **Month** need to select in the table. But i don't have **select id** in the HTML tag.
- But i have **input id** for the **From Month** and **To Month**
- Is there any way to select as the values directly in text box like **Jan 2011** etc.,
- Need example in java with JavaScript executor

Here is the html tag:

```
<input id="fromMonth" class="ui-widget ui-state-default hasMonthpicker" type="text" style="width:55px; padding:4px 3px; font-size:12px; font-weight:normal;color:#606060;" readonly="readonly" name="fromMonth" value="Jan 2013">
<input id="toMonth" class="ui-widget ui-state-default hasMonthpicker" type="text" style="width:55px; padding:4px 3px; font-size:12px; font-weight:normal;color:#606060;" readonly="readonly" name="toMonth" value="Nov 2013">
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

WebElement oRadioBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='toMonth']"));
    oRadioBtn.click();